# How can I check whether a variable is an instance of one of the types in a Union?

Tags: python, typing

I would like to check at runtime that a parameter is of the correct type. So I have something like:

```
MyUnion = Union[Type1, Type2]
```

And what I want to do is something like:

```
def afunc(param: MyUnion):
    # what I want by this is essentially 
    # isinstance(param, (Type1, Type2)) 
    assert isinstance(param, MyUnion)
```

I would have thought this would be simple, but I can't actually find a way of doing this from [the `typing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

My example is simplified. In my actual case the types are being specified dynamically by the client of the tool I'm building, and so I wouldn't expect a static analyzer to be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I didn't find that!